# Adding a service worker to an extension removes the devtools page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, service-worker

I'm trying to create a Chrome extension that adds a DevTools panel and a service worker. In theory, that should be working with the following minimal manifest:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "My Custom DevTools",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "service-worker.js"
  }
}
```

However, using this manifest, the service worker starts, but the devTools page is never loaded by the browser. If I remove the `background` key, the devTools panel shows up as intended.
This configuration is used by several well-known extension (e.g. the Vue/React/Svelte devtools), so it must be possible in principle.

Why does adding a background worker to the extension disable the devtools page?

```js
// register.js
chrome.devtools.panels.create('My Custom DevTools', null, 'devtools-panel.html', (panel) => {
  console.log('DevTools panel was loaded', { panel })
})


// service-worker.js
console.log('Service worker started')
```

```html
<!-- devtools.html -->
<script src="register.js"></script>

<!-- devtools-panel.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="display: flex">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="icon">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <title>My Custom DevTools</title>
  <meta charset="utf8" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Custom DevTools Content</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome.

Comment: I'm not so sure. I have the Vue devtools working in the same browser at the same time, and they define a worker + a panel, too...

Comment: The nonsensical behavior is exactly why it's a bug. There's absolutely no reason for this to happen.